# using Data Object XML with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to print the key value pair from Data Object type XML using a Powershell script.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Objects>
      <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
        <Property Name="Display" Type="System.String">Microsoft</Property>
        <Property Name="Service" Type="Microsoft.Management.Service">Database</Property>
      </Object>
      <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
        <Property Name="Display" Type="System.String">Microsoft</Property>
        <Property Name="Service" Type="Microsoft.Management.Service">RPC</Property>
      </Object>
    </Objects>
```

Here is the script used.

```
[xml]$file = Get-Content C:\xml-report.xml

foreach ($obj in $file.Objects.Object) {
    echo $obj.Display;
echo $obj.Service;
}​
```

How should I iterate through each key (Display, Service) and print only the values of those- i.e

```
Microsoft 
Database 
Microsoft 
RPC
```

The output which I get now is as below. Could someone help me here?

```
Object
Object
Object
```

Comment: `$File.SelectNodes('/Objects/Object/Property')|%{$_.'#text'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are trying to explicitly access the properties with name `Service` and `Display`, here is a solution to directly access those, in case your xml file contains more elements you're not concerned with:

```
foreach ($obj in $file.Objects.Object.Property) {
  if('Display','Service' -contains $obj.Name) {
    write-output $obj.'#text'
  }
}
```

Or in one line:

```
$file.Objects.Object.Property | ? { 'Display','Service' -contains $_.name } | Select '#text'
```

Comment: Thanks Arco.. is it possible to map the value of Display and Service against each other. For example - if i wanted to output as -- "the Service "Database" belong to the Display "Microsoft"".. Sorry if that sounds another question, but just wanted to check.

Comment: It is possible, and it is a different question to the one that is here, so please ask a new one if you can't figure it out on your own. A hint is to iterate over the `$file.objects.object` and assign variables such as: `$service = $obj.Property | ? { $_.name -eq 'Service' }`

Answer (score 0):

You were just omitting the Property element. Your loop would work with a slight modification:

```
[xml]$file = Get-Content "C:\temp\xml-report.xml"

foreach ($obj in $file.Objects.Object) 
{
    $obj.Property | % { $_.'#text' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Powershell version 3 or above you could try use this:

```
[xml]$file = Get-Content C:\xml-report.xml
$file.Objects.Object.Property.'#text'
```